# Python String variable itself in Regex pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

Is it possible to include string variable itself in Regex pattern?

```
text="Sample text is"
st="text"
r=re.findall("[A-Z]+[st]+",text)
print(r[:])
```

Resaon is I need regex pattern in loop, so st string variable will be not fixed and will be changing, so I can not write Regex pattern as just "text". Or it is not possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
>>> import re
>>> text = "Sample text is"
>>> st = "text"
>>> r = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+[%s]+" % re.escape(st), text)
>>> print(r[:])
[]
```

Note that I am escaping the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the Regular Expression, like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[A-Z]+({})+".format(st))
re.findall(pattern, text)
```

You can check the created pattern, like this

```
print pattern.pattern
```

In the above expression, the value in `st` will be substituted in place of `{}`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Note that, I have changed the `[st]` to `(st)`, because `[st]` will match any character in the word `st`. If you want to match the actual word then you might want to group it like I have shown.

But, if all you are trying to do is to check if one string exists in another, then you can use `in` operator, like this

```
if st in text:
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you do :

```
>>> text="Sample text is"
>>> st="text"
>>> if st in text:
...     print('Success')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate regexp strings.

```
import re
pattern1 = "[A-Z]"
pattern2 = "text"
pattern = pattern1 + pattern2

text = "Sample Atext is Ztext"
r = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(r[:])
#['Atext', 'Ztext']
```